# Book where family has to move due to extreme weather conditions

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read this book a while back while I was in middle school (between 1999 and 2001). The book was most likely published some time in the mid to late 90's. I can't seem to remember what it's called and searching for it has turned up nothing.

Here is what I can remember:

- The book is split into 2 major parts.
- The book has a realistic depiction of the future where the environment is getting more extreme due to global warming.
- The first part takes place in an urban environment, where the main character's family lives. But the environment is extremely hot and dry. Fires are a common problem, and the city has a lack of water to properly fight them causing whole blocks to be burned down.
- It's possible that the main character's family dies in one of these fires, or they just send the main character away to get out of the extreme conditions.
- The main character travels North, to colder climates to get out of the extreme heat.
- The remainder of the fist part of the book is him traveling North.
- I recall him walking for most of it, and him talking about how fossil fuels are rare and expensive, and cars are pretty much a thing of the past.
- The second part is his experience once he travels far enough North, only to find that the environment is the other extreme; extremely cold.
- I recall the main character meeting up with another family member (maybe an older sister which had moved out years before).
- I remember one specific scene where the main character and his older sister are using a bike powered generator to power a small heater and a TV (or radio), to try survive the cold environment.

And help finding the title of this book would be greatly appreciated.